# How to access emails sender in Outlook using Pywin32

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, pywin32

I would like to print out some information about emails that have Category="Backlog" for instance. I use [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32) library as below code:

```
import win32com.client
import os, sys
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

def print_messages(messages, sCategory, f):
    msgs = messages.Restrict("[Categories] = '" + sCategory + "'")
    for message in list(msgs):
        try:
            if message.Class == 43:
                if message.SenderEmailType == "EX":
                    strSender = message.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
                else:
                    strSender = message.SenderEmailAddress
            f.write(message.EntryID + "\t" + strSender + message.ConversationTopic + "\t" + message.ReceivedTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") + "\t" + message.Categories + "\n")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Oops!", sys.exc_info()[0], "occurred.")

def main():
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    messages = inbox.Items
    now = datetime.now()
    f = open("C:/Temp/outlook_emails_" + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + ".txt", "a")
    print_messages(messages, "Backlog", f)
    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When this code run, it can't get the email sender. Exception happens and it prints lines like:

```
Oops! <class 'pywintypes.com_error'> occurred.
Oops! <class 'pywintypes.com_error'> occurred.
Oops! <class 'pywintypes.com_error'> occurred.
Oops! <class 'pywintypes.com_error'> occurred.
```

The issue in lines:
`strSender = message.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`
and in line
`strSender = message.SenderEmailAddress`.
Not sure how to correctly access the sender email address!!

Versions used:

- Windows 10 (64-bit)
- Outlook v16 (64-bit)
- Python 3.9.5 (64-bit)
- pywin32 version: 300

Answer (score 0):

You never check that `GetExchangeUser` returns a valid object rather than null. The current profile must contain the original Exchange server that houses the GAL user.

Before using `GetExchangeUser`, check if `PidTagSenderSmtpAddress` MAPI property is available using `message.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F")`

Comment: Adding line: `print(message.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F"))` in the try/catch block, it results in same exception: `Oops! <class 'pywintypes.com_error'> occurred.`